# Hyperelliptic integral involving square root of sextic polynomial

Tags: indefinite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

I am interesting in finding the integral of $$ I = \int \frac{{\rm d}x}{-\sqrt{x^6+x^2-c}}$$ Where $c \leq x^6 + x^2$ such that the integral is always real. I was trying to look at a reduction of 579.00 from the Handbook of Elliptic integrals for scientists and engineers by Byrd and Friedman, i.e.,
$$ \int\frac{{\rm d}x}{a_0x^6 + a_1x^5 + a_2+x^4 + a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0}, $$ But in my case $c \neq -1$ in general. I know Wolfram can solve this equation, but I am interested in learning how to apply the reduction and subsequent integration. Moreover, I am unsure on how to check that the roots of the polynomial form three pairs of points of an involution.

Comment: Doesn't the substitution $x=\sqrt t$ transform the integral into an elliptic integral?

Comment: Hi Paul, sorry, I don't see it. Could you expand a bit?

Comment: Ok, sorry if I'm being obtuse. From your transformation I get: $\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{{\rm d}t}{\sqrt{t}\sqrt{t^3+t+a}}$ From there, I guess I can factor $t^3+t+a$ as $(t-b)(t-c)(t-d)$ with $b\in\mathbb R$ and $c,d\in\mathbb{C}$ being the roots of the cubic. But, I can not seem to find the right formula... am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, I think so. The result should be expressible as an elliptic integral of the first kind. I guess that one must determine if two of the roots of the polynomial are real or not and place $x$ with respect to the real roots.

Comment: Thanks. So, I get two complex roots in general. But then I am lost, I don't know how to express this as an elliptic integral, I can't seem to find the right fórmula. Can you help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To evaluate
\begin{equation}
 I(u,v)=\int_u^v\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^6+x^2-c}}
\end{equation}
it is sufficient to calculate
\begin{equation}
 J(Y)=\int_0^Y\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^6+x^2-c}}
\end{equation}
(by parity, we can take $Y>0$). By changing $t=x^2$
\begin{equation}
 J(Y)=\frac12\int_0^y\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t(t^3+t-c)}}
\end{equation}
where $Y=\sqrt y$. The polynomial $P(t)=t^4+t^2-c t$ in the denominator has a degree 4, the integral can thus be expressed in terms of an elliptic integral of the first kind.

The polynomial $t^3+t-c$ is strictly increasing, it has thus one real root $t=\alpha$ and two complex ones, $t=\gamma$ and $t=\bar{\gamma}$. Moreover, the sign rule for the product of the roots indicates that $\alpha$ and $c$ have the same sign ($\gamma\bar{\gamma}>0$). In the following we take $c>0$, thus $\alpha>0$. Another discussion must be done in the opposite case. Then
\begin{equation}
 P(t)=t(t-\alpha)(t-\gamma)(t-\bar{\gamma})
\end{equation}
Now, we must discuss the value of $y$ with respect to $\alpha$.

If $0<y\le\alpha$
\begin{equation}
 J(Y)=\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^y\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t(\alpha-t)(t-\gamma)(t-\bar{\gamma})}}
\end{equation}
Expression 259.00 of  the "Handbook of Elliptic integrals for scientists and engineers" by Byrd and Friedman (with $a=\alpha,b=0$) gives the result
\begin{equation}
 J(Y)=\frac{g}{2i}F(\varphi,k)
\end{equation}
with
\begin{align}
 g&=(AB)^{-1/2};\hspace{0.5cm}A^2=(\alpha-b_1)^2+a_1^2;\hspace{0.5cm}B^2=b_1^2+a_1^2\\
  k^2&=\frac{\alpha^2-(A-B)^2}{4AB};\hspace{0.5cm}\varphi=\cos^{-1}\frac{(\alpha-y)B-yA}{(\alpha-y)B+yA}\\
  b_1&=\Re\gamma;\hspace{0.5cm}a_1=\Im\gamma
\end{align}
Now if $0<\alpha<y$
\begin{equation}
 J(Y)=\left( \int_0^\alpha+\int_\alpha^y \right)\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t(t-\alpha)(t-\gamma)(t-\bar{\gamma})}}
\end{equation}
The first integral is obtained from the above formula and, from the expression 260.00
\begin{align}
 \int_\alpha^y \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t(t-\alpha)(t-\gamma)(t-\bar{\gamma})}}=gF(\varphi,k)
\end{align}
Here \begin{equation}
      k^2=\frac{(A+B)^2-\alpha^2}{4AB};\hspace{0.5cm}\varphi=\cos^{-1}\frac{(A-B)y+\alpha B}{(A+B)y-\alpha B}
     \end{equation}
the other symbols are the same as above.

Section 3.145 of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik can also be useful.

Comment: thanks for your superb answer. I was taking my time to try to go step by step. If I may, I have a couple of questions. i) What happens if I am interested in an indefinite integral? ii) Why is it sufficient to go from $0$ to positive $Y$?. iii) Does the bar on top of $\gamma$ means complex conjugate? iv) Suppose $a\leq 0$, Is the discussion analogous? can you point the steps that change? v) I don't get where the imaginary number is coming from for the first case and not in the second.

Comment: Finally, you defined $J(Y)$, but afterwards you wrote $y$ for the limits of integration, should this be $Y$?. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: i) indefinite integral corresponds to the calculated results up to an integration constant. ii) positive $Y$ is sufficient as the integrand is an even function of $x$: for $Y<0$ we have $J(Y)=-J(|Y|)$. iii) yes, as the coefficients of the polynomial are real, the complex roots are conjugate to one another. iv) For $\alpha<0$ we have always $y>0>\alpha$, there is only one single case to consider.

Comment: v) The introduction of a negative sign under the radical (and thus of the $i$ factor) allows the quantity under the radical to be positive in the considered region of $t$. This is not the case in the second region. Finally, sorry for the typo I should have written $J(Y)$, it is corrected now.