# Hyperelliptic integral: Piecewise solution (handbook) vs General solution (Wolfram)

Tags: elliptic-integrals

Recently, I posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372408/hyperelliptic-integral-involving-square-root-of-sextic-polynomial) asking for hints on how to solve the integral
$$\int \frac{{\rm d}x}{-\sqrt{x^6+x^2+a}}$$
for which I received an amazing answer. The answer helped me reduce the integral to an elliptic integral which could be solved using the Handbook of Elliptic integrals for scientists and engineers by Byrd and Friedman. The solution though, required information on $a$ as well as the roots of the polynomial in order to choose the right formula.

If you ask [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%20of%201%2F-sqrt%5Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E6%2Ba%5D), to solve this integral it seems to use a general formula that requires no assumptions. Furthermore, while the amplitude of the elliptic function is an arccos in the former, in the later it is an arcsin.

Is there somewhere where I can find the source of this difference or a general formula for such integral that requires no partition of the domain of integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the same as @Paul Enta in his answer
$$I=-\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^6+x^2+a}}=-\frac 12 \int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t} \sqrt{t^3+t+a}}$$

Writing
$$t^3+t+a=(t-\alpha)(t-\beta)(t-\gamma)$$ simplifies the problem and, back to $x$
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma \, (\alpha -\beta )}}\,\,F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(\beta -\alpha ) (x^2-\gamma )}{(\beta -\gamma )
   (x^2-\alpha )}}\right)|\frac{\alpha  (\gamma -\beta )}{\gamma  (\alpha -\beta
   )}\right)$$ which looks a bit nicer than the general formula given by Wolfram Alpha (which does not know the roots).

Now, concening the roots of $t^3+t+a=0$, since $\Delta=-(4+27a^2)$, one is real and it is given by

$$\alpha=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3} }{2}a\right)\right)$$ from which $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are esily obtained from the sum and product of the roots.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering tho where did you get this formula? was it from Wolfram or a Handbook/Table?. Also, is this valid for any $a\in\mathbb{R}/\{0\}$?

Comment: @NoobNoob. No WA; just a little work

Comment: Thanks Claude. I'm sorry if I am being obtuse, but, How did you find the antiderivative? for that specific integral? Is there any handbook/reference with such a formula? All of the formulas from Byrd & Friedman seem to use an arccos for the amplitude, and also seem to be divided by cases, depending on whether the roots are real, complex, etc... I am very interested in finding such tables or references, I want to try to integrate these things by myself, to avoid asking every time I need to solve elliptic integrals.

Comment: @NoobNoob. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5B1%2FSqrt%5Bt%28t-a%29%28t-b%29%28t-c%29%5D%2Ct%5D  and simplify

Comment: Thanks, I was asking because you mentioned no WA in your previous comment.

Comment: @NoobNoob. I just did it after your comment